# Upgrade from Excel 2007 to Office 365: Excel very slow

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have recently upgraded from **Excel 2007** to **Office 365**.

I am finding that as soon as I have a few workbooks open (let us say 6 workbooks of 2MB open without many calculations) or one medium workbook (with lots of calculations - let's say a 15MB that takes 30 seconds to calculate) that I am having problems jumping from one cell to another - even within one worksheet, just to the adjacent cell.

For instance if I am in cell E40, just moving to cell D40 using the arrow key can take 5 seconds.

This is so frustrating, that I just simply use Excel 2007 for anything other than small workbooks.

I have tried the following, but have had no success:

1. Disable animations using the registry
2. Excel Options/Advanced/Disable hardware graphics acceleration
3. Disable addins
4. Looking at Microsoft's help to see if there is anything pertinent http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/02/17/top-10-list-of-performance-issues-in-excel-workbooks.aspx
   (there doesn't seem to be)

Comment: I assume with everything the same, within Excel 2007, these problems do not exist?

Comment: Correct. And even with Excel 2007 open simultaneously with Excel 2013, the Excel 2007 works flawlessly.

Comment: I assume the files are still local?  It might be worth your time to open a support ticket with Microsoft.  The type of delay you appear to have, has to be caused by something simple.

Comment: I spoke with Microsoft - one time support for this issue costs over $250... They did direct me to their technet forum

Comment: I posted this on http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f597d65b-2e94-436c-a704-9ffe6f723623/upgrade-from-excel-2007-to-office-365-excel-very-slow?forum=officeitpro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(After posting on Microsoft's technet forum and getting a reply by a Microsoft Engineer)

It is almost certain that the problem was caused by the graphics card. In fact, an update to the graphics card was provided as an optional update via Windows Update, and after this was installed, Excel 2013 seems to work flawlessly.